# How to compare two multiple fileds in document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

i have collection called "devices". this devices collection have two fields called as "devices" and "totalDeviceNeeds". totalDeviceNeeds have integer value. devices field contain array. I want to get all documents that totalDeviceNeeds > devices array size. How can i do that. I try lot of ways and didnt get correct. I try in nodejs.

Comment: Did you try the **$where** operator?
Something like this, `db.devices.find( { $where: "this.totalDeviceNeeds > this.devices.length" } );`

Comment: yah but not luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all.

i just wrote query code or whatever called. here is this

`db.collection.find({ $expr:{ $lt:[{$size:"$devices"}, "$totalDeviceNeeds"] } }).toArray();`

in this `$lt` meaning less than operation

i used this post to do this.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/is-there-a-way-to-query-array-fields-with-size-greater-than-some-specified-value/54597/2